# Issues with a string count, integers to float, Grade formula based on the number of letters, words, and sentences, in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a program to generate the number of letters, words, and sentences, provided input text.
With these values, I want to generate a number (assessing 'readability level') based on a formula with the numbers from the letters, words, and sentences as the variables.

Please refer to the final section of this code (for the Grade formula).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[1000];
    int i=0, chr=0, st=1, sn=0;

    printf("Text: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    for( i = 0; str[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        chr = chr + 1;
    }

    printf("%d letters\n", chr);

    for (i = 0; i <= chr - 1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            st = st + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d words\n", st);

    for (i = 0; i <= chr - 1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
        {
            sn = sn + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d sentences\n", sn);

    double L = (100.0 * chr / st);
    double S = (100.0 * sn / st);
    double grade = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

    if (grade <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (grade < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %f\n", round(grade));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
}
```

I do not know why the grade formula is producing strange results.

for instance,

Sample input:

```
There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.
```

Sample output :

```
92 letters 
17 words 
1 sentences
Grade 14
```

The letters, words, and sentences are Not strange--they are expected. Grade 14 is strange because I expected Grade 9. I cannot recognize a pattern, just that the characteristic strangeness can be described as the output of Grade is always greater than the expected value, for values expected above Grade 1.

```
to continue, 
-Expected Grade 10 shows output Grade 16
-Expected Grade 8 shows output Grade 15
-Expected Grade 7 shows output Grade 14
-Expected Grade 5 shows output Grade 11
-Expected Grade 3 shows output Grade 10
-Expected Grade 2 shows output Grade 9
```

Expected Before Grade 1 text produces the expected output.

The Grade formula :

index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8

where L is the average number of letters per 100 words in the text & 
S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text

Overall,  I do not know why the grade formula is not generating the expected output.

Comment: How are we supposed to know which results are _strange_ and which are correct? Could you describe what results you're getting with what input and what results you expect?

Comment: Please provide sample input, sample output, and an explanation of what you consider to be _strange_.

Comment: I would make a suggestion on your code.  When you're coding a math problem, gratuitous use of parentheses is encouraged.  It helps to clarify the code by breaking the formulaic bits into understandable segments, doesn't cost anything, and can sometimes provide a useful bit of insight into what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you are concerned about "letters, words, and sentences", why do you care about newlines?  eg, why are you using fgets?  You can probably greatly simplify things if you just read one character at a time.

Comment: I used fgets because the compiler said using puts was dangerous

Comment: The compiler probably warned you about `gets`, not `puts`.  But you want `getchar`

Comment: With ```getchar``` rather than ```puts```, same strange grade output

Comment: in fact, the output is 91 letters (not 92), 16 words (not 17). What is formula to calculate `grade` ?

Comment: index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8, where L is the average number of letters per 100 words in the text, and S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are wrong about letter. In your `input` there are some space character, comma character, etc. So you need to calculate exactly the number of letter (a, b, c, d, e, f, etc) in this sentence.

You can use the function `isalpha` to calculate the number of letters:

```
    for( i = 0; str[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(str[i]))
            chr = chr + 1;
    }
```

Then other for loop to calculate the number of words and sentences, using `strlen(str)` instead of `chr - 1`

```
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            st = st + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d words\n", st);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
        {
            sn = sn + 1;
        }
    }
```

When i test, i got the result:

```
Text: There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.
72 letters
16 words
1 sentences
Grade 9.000000
```